# github action takes too much time to build a simple angular 8 app

Tags: npm, caching, github-actions, angular8

I am using GitHub action for building and deploying angular8 app , but the problem is it takes total (20 mins) to complete.

It is taking a huge time in installing dependencies (13mins) which is strange it should use cache but it is not I guess

So is there any solution available so it could take less time in installing dependencies , what changes I have to make so that total workflow could get completed in less time. please see the screenshot attached

[GitHub action steps image(install dependencies takes 13 mins)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8MKp.jpg)

here is my main.yml file

> name: Angular GitHub CI on:   push:
> branches:
> - main
>
> jobs:   ci:
> runs-on: ubuntu-latest
>
> ```
> strategy:
>   matrix:
>     node-version: [14.x]
>
> steps:
>   - uses: actions/checkout@v2
>
>   - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
>     uses: actions/setup-node@v1
>     with:
>       node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
>
>   - name: Cache node modules
>     id: cache-npm
>     uses: actions/cache@v3
>     env:
>       cache-name: cache-node-modules
>     with:
>       # npm cache files are stored in `~/.npm` on Linux/macOS
>       path: ~/.npm
>       key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
>       restore-keys: |
>         ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-
>         ${{ runner.os }}-build-
>         ${{ runner.os }}-
>
>   - if: ${{ steps.cache-npm.outputs.cache-hit == 'false' }}
>     name: List the state of node modules
>     continue-on-error: true
>     run: npm list
>
>   - name: Install Dependencies
>     run: |
>       npm ci
>   - name: Build & CI
>     run: |
>       npm run build:ci
> ```

> ```
>   - name: Archive build
>     if: success()
>     uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
>     with:
>       name: deploy_dist
>       path: dist
>  # - name: Archive code coverage result
>  #   if: success()
>  #   uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
>  #   with:
>  #     name: deploy_coverage
>  #     path: coverage   deploy:
>   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
>   needs: ci
>   steps:
>     - name: Checkout
>       uses: actions/checkout@v1
>     - name: Download build
>       uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
>       with:
>         name: deploy_dist
>     - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
>       uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@releases/v3
>       with:
>         GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
>         BRANCH: gh-pages
>         FOLDER: deploy_dist/hello-world
> ```

Comment: Please use `actions/setup-node@v3`, pass the input `cache: npm` and remove your manual caching. If the cache still doesn't work, please update your question and let's focus on getting the cache to work first. After that, please open a new question if there are more things unclear.